# Meaning of "tu più non torni"

Tags: meaning, translation

After being asked to translate *«tu più non torni»* on a casual conversation and with a sensible lack of context, I was a bit puzzled and assumed that *«[you] don't ever come back»* could be a valid translation.

Later, in that conversation I was told that it meant *you will return no more*, at least in [Rodolfo's aria](https://www.opera-arias.com/puccini/la-boheme/o-mimi-tu-piu-non-torni/) from *La Bohème*, and most of the usage [examples](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tornare/) on the treccani.it dictionary seem to confirm it.

Was my translation invalid?

Comment: “Oh Mimi, you will return no more.” That’s the translation from the linked video https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=sS8Rzf8E1Qc

Comment: @Hachi, as previously stated, it looks like that's the correct translation for the aria, but I'm not sure if my tentative translation is valid in another contexts.

Comment: What do you mean by “in another context”?

Comment: @Hachi: like if I could say «[you] don't ever come back» with «tu più non torni». Would it be valid?

Comment: The sense is the same, but it is more informal. La Boheme was composed at the end of the 19th century and lyrics reflect Italian language usage at that time.

Comment: @Hachi, I fear that the sense I tried to convey with «[you] don't ever come back» was lost in the translation. I meant it like when instating somebody to refrain from coming back again, like in «don't dare to come back»

Comment: I see, no the sense of “tu più non torni” is not “don’t dare to come back”, but “you’ll never come back...”. I should read the lyrics to understand the Opera context for those words.

Comment: @Hachi, the meaning in the context of that aria is “you’ll never come back...”, I only wanted to know if the same words could also convey the other meaning in a different context.

Comment: “Don’t dare to come back” would be “non (osare) tornare  mai più”, so no.

Comment: Thank you vey much, @Hachi, now it's crystal clear. Feel free to post an answer and cleanup the comments, I'll accept it gladly.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, 0x2b3bfa0. I hope @Hachi will write an answer to your question. Nevertheless, please take into account that it's almost impossible to give an explanation of the meaning or a translation that is always valid without an specific context.

Comment: @Charo - I think translation service is actually off topic.

Comment: @Hachi, you know I'm the first one to flag questions only asking for translations. But I think that assembling what you have already said in the comments, and perhaps adding something about _indicativo_ and _imperativo_ moods, you can give a good, not-just-translation answer.

Comment: @Hachi: Please, see these Meta discussions: https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1281, https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12, https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226. And take into account that this question is really asking for the meaning of an Italian sentence (or, more specifically, whether it can have the meanings explained in the question), not necessarily for a translation of this sentence to English, which would be indeed off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sentence cannot mean “don't ever come back”, which would require the imperative. In Italian the negative imperative is expressed with *non* and the infinitive

> non tornare (mai) più

The form *torni* is a present tense, either indicative or subjunctive (but the latter can probably be excluded from context). The positive imperative is *torna* and never *torni*.

*If* the context makes the subjunctive possible, then it could be something like

> Farò in modo che tu non torni più

*I'll do so you don't ever come back again*. But it is not imperative.

In the sentence there is a displacement of the adverb: *tu non torni più* would be more idiomatic. However, being the text of an opera aria, the displacement is not so surprising.

Comment: "tu più non torni", can also be a poetic phrasing to express "you will never come back", "you are not coming back". For example in the "O Mimì, tu più non torni" aria of Puccini's "La Bohème"